# Comment traduire « a righteous infliction of retribution... » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, ordre-des-mots, formulation-idiomatique, cinéma

> Do you know what "nemesis" means? A [righteous](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/righteous/607901) [infliction](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infliction#English) of
> retribution manifested by an appropriate agent. (dit « Brick Top » (Alan Ford) ds. *Snatch* (2000, Guy Ritchie)).

*DeepL* :

> [...] Une infliction juste de la rétribution manifestée par un agent
> approprié.

Vu l'article *la*, entre autres, la phrase n'est pas très naturelle et moins claire que l'original il me semble, car elle évoquerait la possibilité que la *rétribution manifestée par un agent* « reçoive » une *infliction juste*, ce qui est bizarre.

Sous-titre :

> Tu sais ce que « Némésis » signifie ? « Un juste châtiment,
> légitimement infligé... par l'intermédiaire ou au moyen d'un agent
> approprié. »

Plutôt naturel, mais on dirait que l'adverbe [*légitimement*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9gitimement) sert à répéter le sens de *juste* avec le verbe (qui est substantivé en anglais, *infliction*, certainement inusité en français d'aujourd'hui). Sauf que le contexte c'est qu'on a un chef d'organisation criminelle qui fait une profession de foi.

---

Comment peut-on formuler la traduction pour qu'elle soit plus claire, naturelle et fidèle le cas échéant : choisit-on la voie du sous-titre ou celle de DeepL ou une autre et pourquoi ? Est-on d'accord avec l'emploi de *légitimement* ici, et cette astuce syntaxique rend-elle la phrase moins fidèle au sens de l'original ?

Comment: C'est la peine allégée d'un repenti ?

Comment: Ton analyse est bonne. Pour la fidélité, j'imagine qu'on pourrait écrire "une rétribution légitimement infligée par", mais la traduction avec châtiment est plus naturelle selon moi. Avec juste châtiment, je serais d'accord pour dire que légitimement est plutôt superflu dans le contexte puisqu'on le comprend implicitement. Petit problème, tes trois qualificatifs clair, naturel et fidèle ont chacun des critères différents. Il n'y a pas une seule bonne réponse pour les trois. Cette question est intéressante mais très "opinion-based".

Comment: @Simon Le sens négatif de rétribution (punition) est-il encore vivace au Québec ? Il est présent dans le TLFi mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu en France où une rétribution ne peut aujourd'hui être que positive, donc jamais "infligée".

Comment: Avec un peu de malice (car ce n'est pas habituellement utilisé au sens négatif) on pourrait dire "juste récompense". On pourrais aussi, de façon plus neutre parler de "juste retour des choses".

Comment: deepl is a big mess. Don't use it for literature. This means: un châtiment  justement infligé ou infligé par justice. retribution in English here means: punishment. It means: they got what they deserved.

Comment: En effet le sens négatif de rétribution ne sort pas sur Lapresse. C'est pas tant le sens que l'ordre des mots et la syntaxe qui m'intéresse. La phrase du sous-titre utilise le verbe du substantif (_infliction_, infligé) pour alimenter la portion finale (_manifested by_) de manière naturelle (infliger un châtiment). Ce faisant on perd à mon avis le sens de _manifested_ et il aurait fallu un passif ou un pronominal pour ficeler ça différemment. Le résultat est un domino où les dominos tombent « de plus en plus fort » au fur et à mesure qu'on approche de la fin de la phrase. Ce bruit me dérange.